# Looping within a cursor to find the number of times I have to "fetch next from" cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server, while-loop, database-cursor

I have a record like this and I have to go row by row. So for this I use cursor and fetch next cursors.

```
V-18244            -- beginning of order 1
Mill               -- data belonging to order 1
W/L-1285           -- data belonging to order 1
V-18264            -- beginning of order 2
Mill               -- data belonging to order 2
S-18247            -- beginning of order 3
Mill               -- data belonging to order 3
W/L-1285           -- data belonging to order 3
```

I use this

```
IF PATINDEX('_-[0-9]%',@ITEM1) >0
```

to identify the beginning of the order. Now I need to go to line#2 and line#3 of the first order to get the data.
So I have to fetch next cursor twice. But for the second order I only need to fetch cursor once. How can I solve this?

My idea was to use a loop inside the "while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0" loop  but that is not working

sample code:

```
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

BEGIN
    IF PATINDEX('_-[0-9]%',@ITEM1) >0        ----identify order 1

        BEGIN
            SELECT @ITEM1
                        ---a loop to keep fetching until I find the second order?
            begin
                fetch next from po_cursor into @Item1, @Item2, @Item3
                set @var= @var+1
                SELECT @ITEM1 ,'AFTERFETCH',@var 
            END
            set @var=0
                 END
END
```

Comment: Why use a `CURSOR` at all and not a set-based solution?

Comment: *I have to go row by row* - almost certainly you do not; show some proper sample data and explain exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Larnu: The team has been following this norm for all stored procedures related to order processing. This is just one exceptional case and so I am still looking for a cursor- based solution.

Comment: "The team has been following this norm"   Linear thinking ... let it go.

Comment: *The team has been following this norm for all stored procedures* - just to say, Microsoft SQL Server is one of the leading RDBMS there is in terms of performance, on par and even exceeding Oracle in some benchmarks and outperforming MySql and Postgres - particularly - by 3 orders of magnitude. I would be surprised if you were experiencing this however if you work in a RBAR fashion by default.

Comment: *"The team has been following this norm for all stored procedures related to order processing"* I hope you aren't saying here you are using `CURSOR`s everywhere here; you have a lot of rewrite if so

Comment: With data such as `W/L-1285` I would also make a guess that your tables are not normalised at all, probably this data cotains multiple atomic values? - if you were at least 1NF you wouldn't need to be using string pattern matching to make sense of your own data.

Comment: @Larnu : What would be a set-based solution?

Comment: @stu: Actually this is external data. We have to process and output to an excel file.

Comment: I'm sure if you can show a representative sample of your data and what your output should be, someone can suggest a single query in no time - as is we don't actually know enough about your requirement.

Comment: @stu, Sure , but what am I missing here. What do I put in? Make it a bigger table? I apologize I really dont know what to add more apart from enlarging the reference table

Comment: See [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), [tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)

Comment: A set-based solution would process the data as a set, not row by agonising row, @nibblebytes07 . There would be no looping, no iteration.

Comment: Since RDBMS tables don't have any intrinsic ordering you'll have to show enough columns and code to demonstrate how your records are even getting processed in that order in the first place.